# Throttled serial port using windows and AMD chipset

Tags: drivers

Using pgm LBB   - Liberty Basic Booster with following code:

```
''open "com12:115200,n,8,1,cs0" for random as #serial        ' LB
open "com16:115200,n,8,1" for random as #serial              ' LBB
    start = time$("ms")
    for n = 1 to 10000
      print #serial, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"
    next n
    finish = time$("ms")
    nchars = 10000 * (20 + 2)
    print "Actual time taken = "; finish - start; " milliseconds"
    print "Expected time = "; nchars / 11.520 ; " milliseconds"

close #serial

    end
```

I get terrible response, time should be around 19+ seconds , an is on the developers Laptop with I7 chipset .
On my AMD w10 Desktops I get 220+ seconds
On Dell w10 Laptop I5 chipset I get 30+ seconds
On old Dell Inspiron WinXP  I get 19+ seconds 
Is there any way to increase the speed????

Comment: Voting to close - this is a much better fit on SuperUser vs EESE

Comment: The question is of course off topic here, but will still comment that this may be an issue with bad buffer management, especially if the UART is proxied over USB.  You might be able to work around it by collecting the data you want to send into a large buffer at application level and then handing that over in a single write call.  Could also be that whatever language environment you are working in has badly implemented serial coms that are inefficient in their interaction with some hardware / OS drivers.